# characterization of all periodic tiling of a simple set of Wang Tile

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, computational-complexity

Consider a set of Wang Tile such that all the edges are either 1 or 0.... there are 16 elements in such a set.

Now, I wish to characterize all the periodic tilings of this set (better if they are characterized by the appearing frequency of each type of the tiles)... Is there some way that I could do any such kind of characterization?

Thank you.

Comment: I gather that you are mainly asking about which lists of 16 numbers adding to 1 could be the relative proportions . restricting to the 4 tiles having 1 on the top and bottom edges might be a good start. it is impossible to have the proportions be $1/3$ each for having sides (left right) $00$ $01$ $10$ so a certain obvious condition is not sufficient.